# AWS documentation for: EC2 "Launch more like this"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a running EC2 instance.  I would like to know all about cloning, starting with the obvious feature:

`Right-click on the instance and find "Launch More Like This" ..`

Is there any documentation anywhere?  I have looked all over Amazon's developer documentation.  Is this duplicating disk and memory, just disk, or just the raw AIM image for example?  Thank you...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Launch more like this will launch another instance (or more) with the same settings as the selected instance (EBS, AMI, Security Groups, etc).

If you would like to launch an instance with the exact same data (basically a clone of the selected EC2 instance) you should create an AMI (in case of EBS backed instances, you can create an AMI by right clicking the instance in the Web Console) and launch instances with that AMI.

You can also create AMIs from previous EBS snapshots of your EBS device (also available from the EC2 Web Console).

Comment: i want to clone the amazon ec2 instance i have create the ami for that ec2 but i want to also clone the security groups elastic ips and all the other configurations for that ec2 into other one then i want to stop that instance can you please let me know how can i do this.

Comment: if you start writing cli scripts for this is can get really complex. best bet is to script the setup in CloudFormation (or Terraform) then you can run it whenever you want, keep it up to date, tweak it etc.

Answer (score 4):

Even though this question has an accepted answer I am pasting the details straight from the [AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/launch-more-like-this.html). The following configuration details are copied from the selected instance into the launch wizard:

- AMI ID
- Instance type
- Availability Zone, or the VPC and subnet in which the selected
  instance is located
- Public IPv4 address. If the selected instance currently has a public
  IPv4 address, the new instance receives a public IPv4 address -
  regardless of the selected instance's default public IPv4 address
  setting. For more information about public IPv4 addresses, see Public
  IPv4 addresses and external DNS hostnames.
- Placement group, if applicable
- IAM role associated with the instance, if applicable
- Shutdown behavior setting (stop or terminate)
- Termination protection setting (true or false)
- CloudWatch monitoring (enabled or disabled)
- Amazon EBS-optimization setting (true or false)
- Tenancy setting, if launching into a VPC (shared or dedicated)
- Kernel ID and RAM disk ID, if applicable
- User data, if specified
- Tags associated with the instance, if applicable
- Security groups associated with the instance

The following configuration details are not copied from your selected instance; instead, the wizard applies their default settings or behavior:

- Number of network interfaces: The default is one network interface, which is the primary network interface (eth0).
- Storage: The default storage configuration is determined by the AMI and the instance type

**NOTE**

The Launch More Like This wizard option does not clone your selected instance; it only replicates some configuration details. To create a copy of your instance, first create an AMI from it, then launch more instances from the AMI.

Answer (score 1):

Launch more like this option is not available anymore.

Comment: It's still available in the new UI experience; But under *Image and templates > Launch more like this*