# Create copy of EC2 instance and launch as new instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, snapshot, amazon-ami

I setup one mail server in one EC2 instances. I want to copy the whole instance and launch as another new instance.

I'm very confused about snapshot and AMI, so please suggest how to do it.

Comment: THis has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181849/ec2-instance-cloning

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EC2 Instance Cloning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181849/ec2-instance-cloning)

Comment: ohh thanks @E.J.Brennan

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When talking about creating a copy or clone of an instance, there's two aspects to consider:

- The configuration of the instance itself, such as Instance Type, Security Group, IAM Role and network subnet
- The contents of the disk volume(s)

To launch an instance with the same instance configuration, use the **Launch More Like This** option in the actions menu, which can launch a new instance with the same configuration. This will also select the **original AMI** used to launch the initial instance -- please note that this means it will have the same disk as sued when launching the initial instance, but will not have a copy of all data stored/changed on the initial instance since it was first started.

If you wish to make a perfect copy of the instance, including the contents of the disk volume(s), then **create an AMI** (see documentation for [Linux](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-ebs.html) and [Windows](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/Creating_EBSbacked_WinAMI.html)). This will make a copy of the disk volume(s) so that any instance launched from the AMI will have the same data on disk. Then, launch a new instance from that AMI.